# Unable to install psycopg2 on mac using Interactive installer by EDB

Tags: python, postgresql

**Problem Statement**

Hello guys, I am trying to install psycopg2 to integrate PostGreSQL 14 with Python-Django, on my Mac OS.

I installed PostGreSQL 14 via EBD found on [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/).

When I run on my terminal, the bellow command :

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

I get an error  `Error: pg_config executable not found.`

**Solutions tried without success**

It seems to be a common and well-documented error on the internet. None of the solutions below have worked for me so far :

- 1    `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`

  ```
  Error : missing pg_config
  ```
- 2 `which pg_config`

  ```
  Error : pg_config not found
  ```
- 3 `pip3 install --upgrade wheel` then 'pip3 install psycopg2-binary'

  ```
  Error: pg_config executable not found.
  ```
- 4 `brew install postgresql`

  ```
  Error: zsh: command not found: brew
  ```

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED**

I needed to install [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/index_fr), then run

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH


brew install postgresql

pip3 install psycopg2
```